# (Sporadically) Checksum fail when ORACLE Native Encryption is enabled and there is high workload on the server (with ojdbc8 v. 19.6.0.0)

Tags: java, oracle, encryption, checksum, ojdbc

I have found so far description of this problem related to Native Encryption enabled only when using ojdbc7 with version <= 12.2.0.1.

Unfortunately I am getting this problem also with **ojdbc8 v. 19.6.0.0.**
Our use case are high volume of ETL java jobs running on an IBM AIX server.

After several tries the findings have been the following:

1. The problem doesn't occur if Native Encryption is disabled.
2. With Native Encryption enabled the problem seems occur more often when on the server either the number of parallel runs is increased or there is in parallel another job with an high usage of resource. Indeed the same ETL job doesn't fail if the parallel jobs running on the server is kept low.

The problem seems connected to the workload on the server, not clear if the java server (where are running multiple jobs in parallel) or on the DB server.

Do you have either any experiences or findings related to this behavior? Seems the Native Encryption (ASO) get messed up with high volume of connections/workload.

Here the whole stack trace:

```
java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: Checksum fail
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.fetch(T4CStatement.java:1050)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.fetchMoreRows(OracleStatement.java:3456)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.InsensitiveScrollableResultSet.fetchMoreRows(InsensitiveScrollableResultSet.java:742)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.InsensitiveScrollableResultSet.absoluteInternal(InsensitiveScrollableResultSet.java:698)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.InsensitiveScrollableResultSet.next(InsensitiveScrollableResultSet.java:412)
    ..........................
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Checksum fail
    at oracle.net.ano.CryptoNIONSDataChannel.readDataFromSocketChannel(Unknown Source)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CMAREngineNIO.prepareForUnmarshall(T4CMAREngineNIO.java:784)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CMAREngineNIO.getNBytes(T4CMAREngineNIO.java:598)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CMAREngineNIO.unmarshalNBytes(T4CMAREngineNIO.java:567)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DynamicByteArray.unmarshalBuffer(DynamicByteArray.java:295)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DynamicByteArray.unmarshalCLR(DynamicByteArray.java:210)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CMarshaller$BasicMarshaller.unmarshalBytes(T4CMarshaller.java:129)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CMarshaller$BasicMarshaller.unmarshalOneRow(T4CMarshaller.java:108)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CVarcharAccessor.unmarshalOneRow(T4CVarcharAccessor.java:231)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIrxd.unmarshal(T4CTTIrxd.java:1594)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIrxd.unmarshal(T4CTTIrxd.java:1313)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.readRXD(T4C8Oall.java:888)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:468)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:269)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:655)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.doOall8(T4CStatement.java:229)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.fetch(T4CStatement.java:1037)
    ... 13 common frames omitted
```

Comment: A hardware-test wouldn't hurt, during that running the application on another computer.

Comment: @LorinczyZsigmond: what would you advice to check? if either the CPU or Memory usage will be the same? and what correlation would you make in such cases?

Comment: Ram-problem is possible.

Comment: @LorinczyZsigmond how the RAM should impact the Encription?

Comment: Which checkum (SHA256 for example) and encryption (AES256 for example) are you using?

Comment: @JeandeLavarene Below more details: **locationCryptoNIONSDataChannelklass**: jar:file:....../ojdbc8-19.6.0.0.jar!/oracle/net/ano/CryptoNIONSDataChannel.class
**EncryptionAlgorithmName**: AES256
**EncryptionProviderName**: JavaNet
**ChecksumProviderName**: JavaNet
**DataIntegrityAlgorithmName:** SHA256
**AuthenticationAdaptorName**: 
**java.vendor**: IBM Corporation
**java.version**: 1.8.0_331
**java.runtime.version**: 8.0.7.10 - pap6480sr7fp10-20220505_01(SR7 FP10)

Comment: @Angelo this could be a bug in IBM's JDK. Do you have a way to switch to OpenJDK or Oracle's JDK and verify if the problem reproduces?